# HLS protocol , ParserException: Failed to parse the playlist, could not identify any tags

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, m3u8, exoplayer

I am trying make a video player by HLS protocol and Exo player in Android.
There is a problem.

> Error: "Parserexceptio is: Failed to parse the playlist, could not identify any tags."

Note: There is a player list file. File extention is m3u8. The file is local but videos are at server.

My m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=150000,RESOLUTION=640x352,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
http://example.com/video/1.mp4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=240000,RESOLUTION=640x352,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
http://example.com/video/2.mp4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit the question and provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` tags are used in a Master playlist. A Master playlist points to multiple Media playlists - also `m3u8` - and **not** to the media files.

Since you linked a bunch of `MP4` files instead it will try to open them as `m3u8` and will obviously fail to find the HLS tags, hence the exception.

Your playlist is the blue one:

[image]

I suggest you read more on the [Apple HTTP Live Streaming page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html) and check the rest of the documentation.